# CRUD Tasks using Java via JERSEY REST

Tags: document-library, web-services, rest

I am trying to create a rest webservice using Jersey library.
I want to upload, get, delete and update a document in document library.

Can someone link an example of simple crud. For some reason I can not find any example of it where someone is using Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to use another library to make CRUD operations on SharePoint? You already have SharePoint REST endpoints that you can use for all these purposes.

[Have a look here for Basic Operations in REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. I wanna see how the POST,GET,UPDATE,DELETE requests looks like using jersey.
As you said before, i have the sharepoint rest endpointers but i want to see how the jersey POST request looks like using the sharepoint endpoints urls.

Comment: For an example. How does the  basic authentication looks like using jersey?